# Remove border from QComboBox item

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qtwidgets

I'm trying to style a QtComboxBox and ListView but i'm not sure how to remove this annoying border when an item of the combobox is hovered. Here's what I have

QListView:

```
/*-----QListView-----*/
QListView
{
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:1, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(50, 61, 80, 255),stop:1 rgba(44, 49, 69, 255));
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #191919;
    border-radius: 10px;
    show-decoration-selected: 0;

}


QListView::item
{
    color: #green;
    background-color: #454e5e;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 10px solid #191919;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left : 10px;
    height: 42px;
}

QListView::item:selected
{
    color: #31cecb;
    background-color: #454e5e;
    border: 2px solid magenta;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

QListView::item:!selected
{
    color:white;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding-left : 10px;

}


QListView::item:!selected:hover
{
    color: #bbbcba;
    background-color: #454e5e;
    border: transparent;
    padding-left : 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
```

QComboBox:

```
/*-----QComboBox-----*/
QComboBox
{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}


QComboBox::drop-down 
{
    width: 35px;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Which gives me something like

[image: this]

What I want to do is to remove this grey rectangular selection around the item label, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `border-style:none;` where you don't want to see the border.

for example :

```
QComboBox#comboBoxName{

         border-style:none;

}
```

I also Try this in your code and this is its result:

```
QComboBox::item {
    width: 35px;
    height:35px;
    border-style:none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to add that to all the elements I listed above and it didn't work

Comment: @CplusplusEnjoyer can you add your project to GitHub?or create a simple example there?

Comment: ok https://github.com/Cplusplus-enjoyer/QTThemeTest

Comment: @CplusplusEnjoyer,I see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEGRw.gif and I didn't see any `border-style:none;` in your `SpyBot.qss`.

Comment: hmm, could it be that you are not running on windows? I mean, I had a magenta border set in QListView::item:selected which is not showing up on your gif.

Comment: @CplusplusEnjoyer maybe and you are using it in Visual Studio but I use Qt creator. my Os is Ubuntu 20.04.I update my answer please add that style to your qss file